# Apache won't reload, and apachectl -S / -t doesn't display anything

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

I have an apache configuration problem (Apache 2.4.6 on CentOS 7.2) which I can't ferret out with `apachectl -t`.

Apache runs (*it is started anew every Monday because the system is a virtual box for development*) but shows the "It works!" page only; `apachectl -S` doesn't emit any output. In fact, any execution of the `/sbin/apachectl` script yields no output at all.

Called directly, `/sbin/httpd -t` tells me, "`Syntax OK`" (this had found some errors for which `apachectl -t` had let me down, especially in my macros use).

Probably relevant non-standard features of my configuration:

- I use apache macros (`LoadModule macro_module modules/mod_macro.so`)
- I use symbolic links in my configuration (e.g. links to `sites-available/*.conf` files in a `sites-enabled/` sibling directory which doesn't seem to be used by default in CentOS installations). (No broken links, AFAICS; `httpd -t` would have complained, as I just tested.)

I found the following error in the `journalctl -xe` output: `Could not open configuration file /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/vhosts-vbox-therp.conf: Permission denied`. However, IMHO there is nothing wrong with this file:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. root root /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/vhosts-vbox-therp.conf -> ../sites-available/vhosts-vbox-therp.conf
-rw-r--r--. root root /etc/httpd/sites-available/vhosts-vbox-therp.conf
drwxr-xr-x. root root /etc/httpd/sites-available
drwxr-xr-x. root root /etc/httpd/sites-enabled
drwxr-xr-x. root root /etc/httpd
drwxr-xr-x. root root /etc
dr-xr-xr-x. root root /
```

**Update:**
After elimination of that mentioned symlink, Apache reloaded successfully; however, the rest of the problem persists (no virtual hosts, no `apachectl -S`).

I updated apache (`yum update httpd`; now `2.4.6-45.el7.centos`, was `2.4.6-40.el7.centos` before). Didn't help.

There are still some symbolic links (used via macros), but I have a productive CentOS server where they don't cause problems (`2.4.6.19.el7.centos`).

(... and I fixed a few typos.)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like CenOS may have screwed the apachectl script or the envvars file (or you screwed it yourself).

In any case all apachectl does is load envvars file:

```
. /path/to/apacheinstall/bin/envvars
```

and then call httpd:

```
/path/to/apacheinstall/bin/httpd
```

I would check the contents of both and try to fix what was done wrong or load the environment manually and call httpd directly.

envvars file by default (no distro versions): just adds /path/to/apacheinstall/lib to LD_LIBRARY_PATH
apachectl loads previous file and adds a few commands for you to handle httpd easily.

Comment: I couldn't find any `envvars` file; `/sbin/apachectl` sources a `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` file which contains a `LANG=C` only (besides comments). This, and `{/usr,}/sbin/{httpd,apachectl}` all share the same time stamp (`ls -l`: `18. Jul 2016`, with `--time=ctime`: `22. Nov 13:48`), so I'm innocent of having screwed it myself ...